# Enable The Secret Start Screen Animation for every launch

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

When i first sign onto Windows 8, i get a very cool flow-y animation of all tiles filling up the screen. After that, though, the Start screen has a much more toned-down animation. Is it possible to enable the cooler animation for every launch of the Start screen?

Answer (score 4):

You can use  [**Windows 8 Start Screen Tweaker**](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.146) to customize the animation and to enable it for every time it pops up.

[image]

Caveat:

```
we consider the animations feature as "unstable". Use it at your own risk for 
non-logon purposes
```

**Alternatively** you can also do some **registry tinkering**, to achieve this **without a third party SW**, but this is more involved. The steps are detailed [here](http://winaero.com/blog/enable-advanced-animations-for-the-start-screen-in-windows-8/). The steps are

- Press Win+R on the keyboard and type “**regedit.exe**” without quotes.
- **Navigate to the key** 
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Grid
- Create a **new DWORD value** called Launcher_SessionLoginAnimation_OnShow.  Set it to 1.
- **Enjoy**

Comment: No in-built UI, but this app's just making it easy to perform the necessary registry edits.

Comment: Ya, i figured it had to be possible, needed a smidge more of google

Comment: Any reason you removed the caveat I added (a direct quote from the tool's developer)? Also the source link I added was to the original site (the same one you found the manual steps on).

Comment: @Karan sry bout that, there doesn't seem to be any way to handle merges, my change just destroyed urs  :-(, ive added it back

Comment: NP, I re-added the original link as well. If we're gonna direct people to possibly dodgy 3rd party utils, might as well not add any more dodgy sites to the mix. :)

Comment: ah k, i missed that one

Answer (score 0):

There is a registry tweak available that apparently does this. Instructions are from [here](http://www.askvg.com/registry-tweak-and-freeware-to-enable-secret-animation-in-windows-8-start-screen/).

1. Open the Registry Editor by pressing "WIN+R" and type regedit.
2. Go to following key:

   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Grid
3. Create a new DWORD `Launcher_SessionLoginAnimation_OnShow` and set its value to 1